# node.js request point to response

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I have create a http server with node, I'm wondering the request object can somehow point to the response object. Right now, I'm making a global variable equal to the response and accessing that, but I would like to access the response directly from the request.

```js
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(server_handler).listen(port);

var response_stream_object = {};

function server_handler(request, response) {
  response_stream_object = response;
  request.func(param);
}

http["IncomingMessage"].prototype.func = function(param) {
  // Doing something with response_stream_object
}
```

Comment: Do NOT save the request/response objects in globals or even module variables, ever.  If you have multiple requests being processed at the same time, they will clobber each other if you save them to the same higher scoped variable.  The response variable is only operative for the duration of that specific request anyway so you can just pass them to whatever else needs them when you call another function from within the request handler.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a global variable. It's shared by all requests to your server. Therefore it may be overwritten if another request comes in before you finish processing the current request. This is only OK if you have zero asynchronous processing (no database, no disk access, no network access).

Since this is javascript, of course you can add things to objects (any object) any time you want. For example, you can even add stuff to the built-in `Math` object:

```
// only an example, don't do this:
Math.monkey = "ooh, ooh, aah, aah";
```

So you can simply do:

```
request.response = response;
```

Now the associated response object is directly tied to the request object.

---

But do consider long and hard about your architecture if you need to do this. If you really need to do this then you're probably doing something wrong.